# Is there any disadvantage of running multple Arbiters on one server for different shards?

Tags: mongodb

We have a MongoDB environment with multiple shards. Each shard has one primary, one secondary and an arbiter.

Currently the primaries and secondaries are running on their own hardware; the arbiters (for each shard) are both sitting on the same server under different ports. Is there any disadvantages with having the arbiters all running on the same machine?

My understanding is that they do such little work it isn't an issue, but would love some other opinions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've done something similar in my organization.  We have two arbiters.  One interact with 9 replicas and the other with 8 replicas.  Hasn't been an issue to date.

Comment: Thanks - I thought that it was ok :)